# any suspicious result in that explain analyze?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have the following query :

```
SELECT "message"."id" AS "message_id", "message"."conversation_id" AS "message_conversation_id" 
FROM "communication"."conversation_event" "message" 
LEFT JOIN "communication"."receipt" "receipt" ON "receipt"."message_id"="message"."id" AND ("receipt"."sender_id" != "message"."sender_id")  
LEFT JOIN "communication"."message_notification" "notification" ON "notification"."message_id"="message"."id" 
WHERE ("receipt"."id" IS NULL) 
AND "message"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
GROUP BY "message"."id" 
HAVING COUNT("notification"."id") = 0
```

When running EXPLAIN ANALYZE on it, I got this result, but I dont undertand anything to it:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=29033.74..29033.76 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=1642.748..1642.861 rows=0 loops=1)
  Group Key: message.id
  Filter: (count(notification.id) = 0)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 22454
  ->  Sort  (cost=29033.74..29033.74 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=1632.409..1638.614 rows=22454 loops=1)
        Sort Key: message.id
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2928kB
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=22180.05..29033.73 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=1506.907..1570.545 rows=22454 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((notification.message_id)::text = (message.id)::text)
              ->  Seq Scan on message_notification notification  (cost=0.00..6164.03 rows=183903 width=82) (actual time=0.014..19.183 rows=182741 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=22180.04..22180.04 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=1506.821..1506.931 rows=22454 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 32768 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 2756kB
                    ->  Gather  (cost=1000.55..22180.04 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=90.788..1495.896 rows=22454 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 2
                          Workers Launched: 1
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.55..21179.94 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=87.529..1476.796 rows=11227 loops=2)
                                Filter: (receipt.id IS NULL)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 211337
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on conversation_event message  (cost=0.00..11760.40 rows=495 width=107) (actual time=0.011..51.663 rows=118874 loops=2)
                                      Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 10
                                ->  Index Scan using "UQ_receipt_messageId_senderId_type" on receipt  (cost=0.55..18.99 rows=4 width=107) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=2 loops=237747)
                                      Index Cond: ((message_id)::text = (message.id)::text)
                                      Filter: ((sender_id)::text <> (message.sender_id)::text)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 2
Planning Time: 1.308 ms
Execution Time: 1643.908 ms
```

Is there anything that looks suspicious in it ? This query might be the cause of our server crash, but not sure yet. Recently, we added that column `deleted_at` on `message` table, with no index on it. Does it lead to bad performance on this query ?

Comment: If you converted the two LEFT JOINs to NOT EXISTS subqueries, you could remove the GROUP BY and probably improve speed.

Comment: Your query can be optimized, no doubt. But there is no way it can crash a server. You have more serious problems. At worst, the query can *trigger* a problem lying in wait. But there is not nearly enough information to improve either of your problems. Be sure to have a current, complete **backup**, before you proceed. A Postgres server should *never* crash.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! What does your server log have to say about your crash?

Answer (score 0):

The estimate of rows=495 when the reality is rows=118874 is beyond suspicious, although I don't see it could cause a crash in this query.  The estimation problem in this table could cause some other query to use too much memory, though, provoking the wrath of the OOM killer.

After adding a column, you should analyze the table.  Otherwise the system has no idea how selective `deleted_at IS NULL` will be and makes absurd assumptions.